# How to disable a dropdown menu after a button click in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dropdown menu containing currency values, and a new page loads with the selected currency as a value in the URL. The code for that is as follows:

```
<div id="procurselect">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="chosedCur"><?php echo $curr ; ?></a>
    <ul style="display: none;">
        <li><a rel="nofollow" title="Euro" onclick="set_currency('http://www.example.com/product.php?pid=<?php echo " $pid " ;?>&cur=EUR');" href="javascript:void(0)" target="_top" rel=nofollow>EUR</a>
        </li>
        <li><a rel="nofollow" title="Pound Sterling" onclick="set_currency('http://www.example.com/product.php?pid=<?php echo " $pid " ;?>&cur=GBP');" href="javascript:void(0)" target="_top" rel=nofollow>GBP</a>
        </li>
        <li><a rel="nofollow" title="Canadian Dollar" onclick="set_currency('http:/www.example.com/product.php?pid=<?php echo " $pid " ;?>&cur=CAD');" href="javascript:void(0)" target="_top" rel=nofollow>CAD</a>
        </li>
        <li><a rel="nofollow" title="Australian Dollar" onclick="set_currency('http://www.example.com/product.php?pid=<?php echo " $pid " ;?>&cur=AUD');" href="javascript:void(0)" target="_top" rel=nofollow>AUD</a>
        </li>
        ........(cont....)
    </ul>
</div>
<script>
    imitSelect.show({
        Target: $('#procurselect'),
        Width: 30
    });
</script>
```

I have another add product button on my page using `simplecart.js`.
The button code is as follows:

```
<a class="item_add" href="javascript:;">
    <img src="images/addtocart.png" alt="Add to Cart" width="197" height="58" />
</a>
```

I want the above currency dropdown to be disabled once a user clicks on the addcart button so that he cannot change the currency again from the dropdown.

I am using jQuery.
How is this possible in jQuery?

**Update:**

I need the **disabled option to persist on all pages**....

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

HTML:

```
<a class="item_add" onclick="disableDropdown()">
  <img src="images/addtocart.png" alt="Add to Cart" width="197" height="58">
</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
  function disableDropdown(){
    $("#procurselect").attr('disabled','disabled');
    //or another option
    $("#procurselect").css('pointer-events','none'); // this makes it unclickable
    //or another option
    $("#procurselect").prop( "disabled", true );
  }
</script>
```

Comment: ..It is working except that when we go to another page. It is getting enabled again...It should persist on another page..How is that possible ??

Comment: Sorry, i did not understand. Unless it is disabled permanently user can change currency again on another page...How to add class to procurselect ??

Comment: when you go to another page, you can check is that div is enabled or disabled. depending on that set enabled or disabled property on onload page event.

Comment: How can it be possible without using cookies or sessions ??

Comment: It does not related to session or cookies..plain js

Comment: Javascript variables remain only on the page on which it is. How can it be possible to transfer a disabled value to another page..Sorry, As noted above i am a newbie in jQuery..I am unable to understand...

Comment: first JS:
`flag=false;
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".item_add").click(function() {
   $("#procurselect").attr('disabled','disabled');
   flag=true;
 });
});`

2nd JS:
`$( window ).load(function() { 
 if(flag){
  $("#procurselect").attr('disabled','disabled');
 }

});`
suppose there are 2 html pages and 2 js. include these both js in both html.
with this flag varible you can decide whether to keep it enable or disble on all pages

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".item_add").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();

     //jQuery (< 1.7):

     //This will disable just the div
     $("#procurselect").attr('disabled','disabled');

     //OR

     //This will disable everything contained in the div
     $("#procurselect").children().attr("disabled","disabled");

     //jQuery (>= 1.7):

     //This will disable just the div
     $("#procurselect").prop('disabled',true);

     //OR

     //This will disable everything contained in the div
     $("#procurselect").children().prop('disabled',true);
   });
});
```

Comment: Just a caution note: The selected value of dropdown won't submit to server if you set it to `disabled`. I found the other solution `$("#procurselect").css('pointer-events','none'); // this makes it unclickable`  more useful

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.item_add').click(function(){
    var pro = $('#procurselect ul li');
    pro.each(function(){
        //Now you have no onlick handler.
        this.onclick = null;
        /*you can also
        this.setAttribute('disabled', true);
        */
    });
});
```